# Conditional sum formula in Crystal reports

Tags: crystal-reports, sum, formula, conditional-statements

I need a help to do sum in Crystal reports:
Here is the sample data:

```
Seq | Name   | Score | used  |Multiply|
1   | Name 1 | 60    | True  | Yes    |
2   | Name 2 | 70    | False | No     |
3   | Name 3 | 56    | False | No     |
4   | Name 4 | 45    | True  | No     |
5   | Name 5 | 55    | True  | Yes    |
6   | Name 6 | 20    | True  | No     |
7   | Name 7 | 80    | False | No     |
8   | Name 8 | 75    | False | No     |
9   | Name 9 | 90    | False | No     |
10  | Name 10| 40    | True  | No     |
11  | Name 11| 60    | False | No     |
12  | Name 12| 50    | True  | No     |
```

I need to calculate sum of TOP 4 rows (Where score is higher) and "Used"= true and if "multiply" = yes then score multiply by 2. and display in group header.

```
      (Row1 x 2) + Row4 + (Row5 x 2)+ Row 12
Like  (60 x 2 ) +  45  +  (55 x 2 ) + 50
```

Please help

I have added global variable at top group and set to zero. Then sum and conditions in details area. It works well but I need to show result in Group header 1. Sum works fine and show correct values in details section and footer but I want to show total on top. I found that whilereadingrecords or sub report may work here, but dont know how to use either

Comment: where are you struck? what have you tried?

Comment: Hi I have added global variable at top group and set to zero. Then sum and conditions in details area. It works well but I need to show result in Group header 1. Sum works fine and show correct values in details section. but I want to show total on top.